# how db_password is visible in wordpress themes or plugin

Tags: wordpress

i noticed today that if enter DB_PASSWORD in a theme file, my password is visible. I think it's posible that an evil theme maker can mail the password or config datas along with the site name. Is it security blunder or it can just be avoided

Comment: Simple solution is to not use dodgy plugins and themes.

Comment: What difference is it than the plugin just running an evil SQL query directly from the plugin?

Comment: Please what do you mean by "dodgy"

Comment: dodgy /dɒdʒi/ *adjective* BRITISH informal - dishonest or unreliable. "potentially dangerous"

Comment: Thanks. This means i should only get themes/plugins on wordpress site only